# JS: ERROR Response with status: 200 for URL: null

Tags: typescript, ssl, https, nativescript

I have the problem when using https.

I tried this code:

```
 public output(): Observable<Item> {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    return this.http.get("https://xx.xxx.xx.xx:4433/login", {
      headers: headers
    })
      .pipe(map((response: Response) => {
        console.log('response', response)
        let res = response.json();
        if (res.StatusCode === 1) {
        } else {
          return new Item('');
        }
      }));
  }
```

This code show in her part `console.log('response', response)` this

JS: ERROR Response with status: 200  for URL: null

Can you ask me any idea?

When change   `constructor(private http: Http) { }` to   `constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }`

show this error:

```
JS: ERROR {
JS:   "headers": {
JS:     "normalizedNames": {},
JS:     "lazyUpdate": null,
JS:     "headers": {}
JS:   },
JS:   "status": 0,
JS:   "statusText": "Unknown Error",
JS:   "url": null,
JS:   "ok": false,
JS:   "name": "HttpErrorResponse",
JS:   "message": "Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error",
JS:   "error": {
JS:     "originalStack": "Error: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.\n    at new ZoneAwareError (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.smartglass/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:1298:33)\n    at onRequestComplete (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.smartglass/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/http/http-request/http-request.js:45:34)\n    at Object.onComplete (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.smartglass/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/http/http-request/http-request.js:37:13)",
JS:     "zoneAwareStack": "Error: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorE...
```

Import:

```
   import { Injectable , NgZone } from "@angular/core";
    import { Item } from "./item";
    import 'rxjs/operators';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
    import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
    import { Http, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';
    import { HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
```

Comment: How is this related to NativeScript?

Comment: I can't understand your question :(

Comment: This is Angular-related (even if you're writing it inside a Nativescript application) Why do you use this content type? This kind of content type is used for the web and for what I know, for POST request. What is the expected results? Can't you work with text or JSON?

Comment: I create a app in Nativescript, that click a button and call this function, like in post. From this function I want to show html content that has login. `"https://xx.xxx.xx.xx:4433/login"`

Comment: @anthares it is nativescript related, i have encountered the same issue multiple times but my fix for it has already been used in the OP's code. doing the same call in an angular web project will work, its to do with nativescript

Comment: good would be to include imports too

Comment: @MarekMaszay I include and import.

Comment: Check this thread https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/5157#issuecomment-352721710

Comment: Have  some way to ignore ssl ?