# JS: Https.request error ReferenceError: okhttp3 is not defined

Tags: angular, https, nativescript

I follow this https://github.com/gethuman/nativescript-https

Install: `tns plugin add nativescript-https`
Write this code:

```
public output() {
    Https.request({
      url: 'https://xxx.xxx.x.x/output?pass=1&out1=1',
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Basic ZWx1c3VhcmlvOnlsYWNsYXZl',
          'x-uuid': 'aHR0cHdhdGNoOmY',
          'x-version': '4.2.0',
          'x-env': 'DEVELOPMENT',
      },
  }).then(function(response) {
      console.log('Https.request response', response)
  }).catch(function(error) {
      console.error('Https.request error', error)
  })
    }
```

command: `tns run`
show this:

```
JS: nativescript-https > Disabled SSL pinning by default
JS: Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
JS: Https.request error ReferenceError: okhttp3 is not defined
```

Comment: do you need to use that plugin? the build in angular http method will do everything you need

Comment: I don't know which is a good way. I want only to get this url: `'https://xxx.xxx.x.x/output?pass=1&out1=1'`

Comment: then simply use the angular http package which you will already have, instead of installing 3rd party libs that arent needed

Comment: I tried like this code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51608761/js-error-response-with-status-200-for-url-null?noredirect=1#comment90185969_51608761  but show error. Can you ask me what isn't correct please?

Comment: that error is a typically server issue, i have had it multiple times, talk to whoever wrote the server code

Comment: When I call this url from the browser, it works. Only by app does not work.

Comment: is cors enabled on your server?

Comment: Yes, is enable cors

Comment: then my best guess is that you have made the call incorrectly, after forgetting to add the `.map()` to the http call, i only get 200 errors when the server returns something incorrectly

Comment: you are talking about this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51608761/js-error-response-with-status-200-for-url-null?noredirect=1#comment90185969_51608761  ?

Comment: no, i am talking from personal experience, you only get 200 errors if you forget to add the `.map()` (which you have got) and if the server returns something incorrectly

Comment: Yes, thank your, but I can't understand in which part I forgot to add `.map()` ?

Comment: you havent forgot to add it, i never said you did

Comment: Ohh sorry please.

Comment: In fact in server request is sent, but the server response status: 200 for URL: null. But I can't understand why when I send this request from browser, server response correctly

Comment: my best guess is the cors config on the server, beyond that, make sure the call is exactly the same and from the same version of the http module if you can

Comment: `"@angular/http": "~6.0.0"`

Comment: is that on mobile and on web?

Comment: it is in mobile

Comment: what about in your angular web app? what version does that use?

Comment: Web app:  `"@angular/http": "^5.2.3",`

Comment: make sure it is on the same version as your mobile app and try again

Comment: Ok, I try it. Thank you